# Output json with using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to ajax, and I quite don't understand how could I output `json` objects with `console.log`.
Without added `.val()` output is working, but when I add `.val()` to the search query, it doesn't seem to work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".form-inline").submit(doStuff);
});

function doStuff(e){
e.preventDefault();

var input = $("#nanizankaInput").val();
var link = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=";
link = link + input; 

$.ajax({
    url: 'link',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
}
```

> FiddleJS: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld9f0ant/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I've completely understood everything in the question, but I can see a problem with the code.

Maybe replace `url: 'link'` with `url: link`.